# Is "Outside the house were two women talking" a grammatical/good sentence? partial inversion vs full inversion

Tags: subject-auxiliary-inversion

Oxford Guide to English Grammar; John Eastwood; Oxford University Press 1994-09

Page 56-57

[image]

> 3 Inversion after an adverbial
>
> a In this sentence the pattern is subject + verb + adverbial of place.
>
> *A furniture van was outside the house.*
>
> When the adverbial of place is in front position, there is inversion of the subject and the ordinary verb *be*.
>
> *Alan walked along Elmdale Avenue and found number sixteen without
>   difficulty. **Outside the house was a furniture van.***
>
> The adverbial *(outside the house)* is in front position to link with what has gone before. The new information *(a furniture van)* comes at the end of the sentence.
>
> We can do the same with other verbs of place and movement, e.g. *come, go, lie, sit,stand*.
>
> *The room contained a table and four chairs. **On the table lay a newspaper.***
>
> *The palace is heavily guarded. **Because inside its walls sit the European leaders.***
>
> With such verbs, a pattern without inversion is possible but less usual.
>
> *On the table a newspaper lay.*
>
> There is no inversion with most other kinds of verbs.
>
> *Outside the house **two women were talking.***
>
> NOT *Outside the house were talking two women.*
>
> NOTE **For *There*** was a furniture van outside the house, • 50

---

related: [subject vs subject-complement; inversion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183826/subject-vs-subject-complement-inversion)

Comment: That is not a hard-and-fast rule. Attestations can be found for  *Outside were two women talking* and *Outside were talking two women* and analogues of that pattern, though normally you'd have *there were*.

Comment: Are you questioning the sentence in the grammar guide, or are you asking if the *different* sentence in the title of your question is acceptable?

Comment: If you inserted a comma after "two women", the sentence would surely be quite OK. "Outside the house were two women, talking" or maybe "Outside the house were two women, knitting".

Comment: @Jason Bassford the *different* sentence, which I thought about while reading the book.